# onClick function for array of buttons not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here the List get's 'n' values from the app.component. I am trying to write onclick function for each of the buttton. Here, is the code

```
onChildButtonClick = (val) => {
console.log(val);}



function makeButton(data) {
return (
     <button onClick = {this.onChildButtonClick.bind(null, data.name)} > 
        {data.name} </button>
);}

const List = (props) => {
    const {projectnames} = props
    return (
        <tr>
        <div> {
            projectnames.map(makeButton, this)
        }
        </div>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

When I try to execute it throws me an error onChildButtonClick is not defined.

Comment: can you share full code of class

Answer (score 1):

As your code stands above, you're referencing `this.onChildButtonClick` which is looking within the scope of the function. But your function `onChildButtonClick` is outside of that scope.

Edit:

I haven't had a chance to test it, but try this out:

```
function makeButton(data) {

  const onChildButtonClick = (val) => {
    console.log(val);
  }

  return (
       <button onClick = {onChildButtonClick.bind(this, data.name)} >
          {data.name} </button>
  );
}

const List = (props) => {
    const {projectnames} = props
    return (
        <tr>
        <div> {
            projectnames.map(makeButton, this)
        }
        </div>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

Comment: So what do I do now?

Comment: Try removing the "this" from `this.onChildButtonClick`.

Comment: See edit... Didn't have a chance to test, but it might fix the scope issue.

Comment: @danielcliff, then consider accepting this answer if it helped you, please.